# Export Excel report from an Excel datasource JasperReport

Tags: java, excel, xlsx, ireport

I'm trying to automatically create report from an existing jasperreport template, I have already done this with CSV files, this is part of the code for CSV files :

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("ReportTitle", "Address Report");
parameters.put("DataFile", name+".csv - CSV data source");
Set states = new HashSet();
states.add("Active");
states.add("Trial");
parameters.put("IncludedStates", states);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("../Desktop/Test/"+name+".jasper", parameters, getDataSource(name));

JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,  "../Desktop/Test/"+name+format.format(new Date())+".pdf");
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "../Desktop/Test/"+name+format.format(new Date())+".pdf");
```

but I didn't find anything related to xlsx files or if there are any libraries that can help in this job, if anyone has any help or idea, I would appreciate it

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've found the answer,
Methods like `setParameters()` and others have been deprecated in the newer versions of iReport. If you still want to use it you can download `4.5.0` libraries or lesser version
This website has some good information on how to solve this problem : http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsxdatasource/index.html

I hope this may help

Answer (score 1):

you can use 
[JRXlsxExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRXlsxExporter.html)

Here [Demo](http://www.massapi.com/class/jr/JRXlsxExporter.html) ,

```
JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, destFile.toString());
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);

exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: There has been a lot of change in the new updates and some methods have been deprecated, but thanks for the help.

Comment: But that demo has some good informations that I've needed, so thank you again sir